# WPML Translating a term/taxonomy programmatically

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, plugin-wpml

I have all terms in English and I am creating/duplicating the same ones for German language by using foreach on english terms and this way i create all terms for German language.

The problem is when i need to assign an German term to its English version.

I tried the trick with TRID like this:

```
$trid = $sitepress->get_element_trid($englist_term_id, "taxonomy_name");

$sitepress->set_element_language_details($new_term_id, "taxonomy_name", $trid, $lang_code, $sitepress->get_default_language());
```

The problem is that $trid does not take any value (The first line of the above code)

Probably there is some other way to accomplish this!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution.

Actually taxonomy name on icl_translation table is stored with prefix called "tax_" which means taxonomy. The above code would work like this:

```
$trid = $sitepress->get_element_trid($englist_term_id, "tax_taxonomy_name");

$sitepress->set_element_language_details($new_term_id, "tax_taxonomy_name", $trid, $lang_code, $sitepress->get_default_language());
```

The difference is tax_ prefix.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[@agon-xheladini](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/309046/83335) is totally correct with his answer.

But this did not work for me as the [WPML API](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_set_element_language_details/) wants to have the [`term_taxonomy_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) instead:

> element_id(bool) Use **term_taxonomy_id for taxonomies**, post_id for posts

So, you should always ensure that you do not use the `term_id`:

```
$originalElementId = get_term($original_term_id)->term_taxonomy_id;

$trid = $sitepress->get_element_trid($originalElementId, "tax_" . $taxonomy);
$sitepress->set_element_language_details(
    get_term($new_term_id)->term_taxonomy_id,
    "tax_" . $taxonomy,
    $trid,
    $lang_code,
    $sitepress->get_default_language()
);
```

**Why?** `term_taxonomy_id` and `term_id` are stored in different WordPress database tables. For usual installations, they have both the same ID for the same term (auto-increment). But I had some installations where the auto increment was different (perhaps a tool "cleared" entries?).